# Properly iterating values inside of a for loop

Tags: python

I have a function that generates an appended string in a for loop from values I have saved in the variable `batch_values`, which is a list with ~80 string values. I then use the appended string to execute the code that is saved in the final appended string.

Like so:

```
part_to_append_1 = ''
for i in batch_values:
    part_name = i.split("x")[0]
    part_value = i.split("y")[1]
    part_to_append = f"({part_name} = '{part_value}'),"
    part_to_append_1 = part_to_append_1 + part_to_append

query = f'''EXECUTE {part_to_append_1};'''
run_query(query);
```

What I'm trying to do now, is to have the `run_query` be executed every time I iterate over `i` 10 time and then continue until `batch_values` list is finished. This is what I tried:

```
for i in batch_values:
    part_to_append_1 = ''
    while (i<=10):
        part_name = i.split("x")[0]
        part_value = i.split("y")[1]
        part_to_append = f"({part_name} = '{part_value}'),"
        part_to_append_1 = part_to_append_1 + part_to_append

    query = f'''EXECUTE {part_to_append_1};'''
    run_query(query);
```

But this doesn't generate the desired result. What is the correct way do this?

Comment: Do you want to run de query every 10 batch values?

Comment: Yes. Run `run_query` for every 10 `batch_values`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work as written because `i` isn't an int, it's a value from `batch_values`

This should give you the output you were trying to get:

```
next_batch = ''
for i, value in enumerate(batch_values, start=1):
    part_name = value.split("x")[0]
    part_value = value.split("y")[1]
    part = f"({part_name} = '{part_value}'),"
    next_batch += part
    
    if i%10 == 0:
        query = f'EXECUTE {next_batch};' #should not be triple quotes
        run_query(query);
        next_batch = '' #clear query buffer

else: #when for loop completes with breaking run whatever was left in the buffer
    if next_batch:
        query = f'EXECUTE {next_batch};' #should not be triple quotes
        run_query(query);
        next_batch = ''
```

Note the last `else:` block is on the `for:` loop, not the `if:` block.
A for/else or while/else block runs when the loop completes without a break command being called.

Comment: `if i%10` needs to be `if i % 10 == 0:` Otherwise the query is run 9 times out of 10 rather than 1 time out of 10.

Comment: you're right. dangers of trying to write code on mobile. edited.

Comment: Since there is no condition where the for-loop is broken, you could just drop the else and de-indent the following if-statement.

Comment: I like this solution the best. Thank you!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski While you're correct the for/else is not explicitly required in this case, its not clear if there could be more conditions he might add outside of this minimally reproduceable example, which would make the for/else a necessity  For example - there should probably be a `try/except` block around the `.split()` calls incase some entry in the batch_values is not formatted as expected and is missing the x or y, and maybe that should force the entire batch to stop without crashing the program.
 The else: block also makes it explicit that we're handling the final batch query there.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you:

```
part_to_append_1 = ''

for num, i in enumerate(batch_values, start=1):
    if num%10 == 0:
        part_to_append_1 = ''
        
    part_name = i.split("x")[0]
    part_value = i.split("y")[1]
    part_to_append = f"({part_name} = '{part_value}'),"
    part_to_append_1 = part_to_append_1 + part_to_append

    if num%10 == 0 or num == len(batch_values)-1:
        query = f'''EXECUTE {part_to_append_1};'''
        run_query(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse your code without changes:

```
chunk_size = 10
data = batch_values
for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size):
    batch_values = data[i:i+chunk_size]
    ...     # your code as is

# restore the initial state
batch_values = data
del data
```

Let's do it as a decorator:

```
def feed_in_chunks(chunk_size):
    def wrapper(procedure):
        def f(data, *args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size):
                procedure(data[i:i+chunk_size], *args, **kwargs)
        return f
    return wrapper    

@feed_in_chunks(10)
def my_function(batch_values):
    # The original code
    part_to_append_1 = ''
    for i in batch_values:
        part_name = i.split("x")[0]
        part_value = i.split("y")[1]
        part_to_append = f"({part_name} = '{part_value}'),"
        part_to_append_1 = part_to_append_1 + part_to_append

    query = f'''EXECUTE {part_to_append_1};'''
    run_query(query);
```